# How to make text stay in the same position relative to an image when resizing?

Tags: html, css

How do I make it when the image resizes, the text stays in the same position relative to the image when it resizes. Footer text must contain the same spaces between columns.

Here what i got now:

[full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSbC3.jpg)

[Resized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNF7R.jpg)

The text does not stay in the same place when the image went smaller, How do I make the text stay in the same place?

This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 logo">
                <!-- LOGO -->
                <a href="/" class="navbar-brand navbar-left">
                    <div class="logo"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="LOGO"></div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6" id="text">
                <h1>DELIVERING SPRING 2017</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- VIDEO-->

        <div class="container" id="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div align="center" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                    <video autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item">
                        <source src="CannonStreet_Timelapse_1280.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- FOOTER-->

        <section id="footer">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2 left-col">
                        <p><a class="contacts" href="#">CONTACTS</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 contact-person">
                        <h2>STUART LAWSON</h2>
                        <p>20 7409 8920</p>
                        <p>07870 555 930</p>
                        <p><a class="email" href="#">slawson@savills.com</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 contact-person">
                        <h2>JOSH LAMB</h2>
                        <p>020 7409 8891</p>
                        <p>07976 988 486</p>
                        <p><a class="email" href="#">jlamb@savills.com</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 contact-person">
                        <h2>SAM BOREHAM</h2>
                        <p>020 7710 7963</p>
                        <p>07917 635 465</p>
                        <p><a class="email" href="#">samb@gmreal.com</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 contact-person">
                        <h2>DAN ROBERTS</h2>
                        <p>020 7710 7963</p>
                        <p>07801 143 909</p>
                        <p><a class="email" href="#">danr@gmreal.com</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 right-col">
                        <h2><a class="info" href="#">info@theriverbuilding.com</a></h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section> <!-- END END FOOTER -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background: url("../img/background.jpg")no-repeat ;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}


/***HEADER**/

.logo img {
    margin: 40px 45px;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'GothamMedium', sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    right: 45px;
    top: 150px;
    font-size: 1.55em; /*19pt in psd*/
    color: #ffffff;
}

/***VIDEO***/

#container {
    padding-top: 200px;
}


/*** FOOTER ***/

.col-md-2 {

}

#footer {
    padding: 100px 45px 0;
}

.left-col {
    padding: 110px;
    margin-left: -75px;
}

.right-col {
    padding: 86px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 76px;
}

#footer p {
    font-family: 'GothamBook', sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1.063em; /*13pt in psd*/
}

#footer .email {
    font-family: 'GothamBook', sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1.063em; /*13pt in psd*/
}

#footer .contacts {
    font-size: 1.063em; /*13pt in psd*/
    font-family: 'GothamBook', sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#footer h2 {
    font-family: 'GothamBook', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.063em; /*13pt in psd*/
    color: #ffffff;
}

#footer a:hover {
    color: #0e6655;
    outline: none;
}

#footer .info {
    font-family: 'GothamMedium', sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1.5em; /*15pt in psd*/
}

/***MEDIA QUERIES***/

@media(max-width: 400px){
    #header .logo img{
        margin: 15px 0 20px;
        height: 100px;
    }
    #header h1{
     font-size: 15px;
     text-align: center;
     margin-left: 0;
     margin-right: 0;
    }
    .left-col {
       padding: 0 0 0 0;
    }

    .right-col {
        padding: 0 ;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}

@media(max-width: 768px){
    #header .logo img{
        margin: 15px 0 20px;
        height: 120px;
    }
    h1{
        font-family: 'GothamMedium', sans-serif;
        position: absolute;
        right: 45px;
        top: 165px;
        font-size: 1.55em; /*19pt in psd*/
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    #footer{
        text-align: center;
    }
    .info{
        padding-top: 50px;
    }
    .left-col {
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        padding-top: 0;
    }
    .right-col {
        padding: 86px;
        position: absolute;
        right: 45px;
    }
}

@media(max-width: 1400px){
    .logo img {
        margin: 40px 45px;
    }
    h1 {
        font-family: 'GothamMedium', sans-serif;
        right: 45px;
        top: 150px;
        font-size: 1.55em; /*19pt in psd*/
        color: #ffffff;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #footer .info {
        font-family: 'GothamMedium', sans-serif;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-size: 1.5em; /*15pt in psd*/
        margin-left: -50px;

    }
    #footer .contacts {
        font-size: 1.063em; /*13pt in psd*/
        font-family: 'GothamBook', sans-serif;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    #footer p {
        font-family: 'GothamBook', sans-serif;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-size: 1.063em; /*13pt in psd*/
    }
    #footer .email {
        font-family: 'GothamBook', sans-serif;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-size: 1.063em; /*13pt in psd*/
    }
    .right-col {
        padding: 86px;
        position: absolute;
        right: 45px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this at the end of yor CSS:

```
#footer * {
      margin-left: 2%;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I would set class "row" and "md-col-6" lie:

```
.row {
width: 100%;
display: block;
position: relative;
}

.row .md-col-6 {
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
right: 100px;
}
```

all those factors based on the location you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks!  setting class "row" and "md-col-6" this method worked for me.